# Authorization has been denied for this request - New Web API Project

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I just created new Web API project (using MVC) in visual studio 2015 and for the testing purpose, I ran that project but ended up below error.

After running the project, it brings up Home Page correctly but when I navigated to /api/values or /api/values/5, it gives me below xml message.

```
<Error>
    <Message>Authorization has been denied for this request.</Message>
</Error>
```

Can someone please help? I am new to Web API.
Please note that I don't want to remove the Authorize attribute. I would like to access the resource after authorization only. So I am looking for what is wrong.

Answer (score 82, accepted):

In the ValuesController there is an attribute `Authorize` if you remove it, then it will work as home page.

The `Authorize` attribute just prevent an anonymous  users from accessing the `ValuesController`.

to work with this attribute, you need  first to register a user, and then  login to get user's token, then you can use the token to authorize your self and get access .

In this page [Individual-accounts-in-web-api](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/individual-accounts-in-web-api) is explained all what do you need

Answer (score 26):

It happens because you have an [Authorize](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute(v=vs.118).aspx) attribute on your `ValuesController`

```
[Authorize]
public class ValuesController : ApiController
```

Just remove `[Authorize]` and try again

**EDIT**

According to your edit: You should create a new user and login or use `[AllowAnonymous]` as mentioned by @Marcus H. Read more about Identity

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer here.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/29405794/8107314

And it was very useful to fix my error my error

I just came across the same problem and found the solution:

You need to register the OAuth Token Generator and OAuth Token Consumer things before WebAPI is registered.

Kind of makes sense if you think of this as a pipeline, where Authentication/Authorization should come before any request handling by the controllers.

TL;DR: Change

```
appBuilder.UseWebApi(config);

this.ConfigureOAuthTokenGenerator(appBuilder);
this.ConfigureOAuthConsumer(appBuilder);
```

To

```
this.ConfigureOAuthTokenGenerator(appBuilder);
this.ConfigureOAuthConsumer(appBuilder);

appBuilder.UseWebApi(config);
```