# Authorization token works fine in Postman but not on my device

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, xamarin, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to consume REST API  implemmenting it with  MVVM using Xamarin. I wrote [Authorize] in the controller of my class and when I get the token in Postman I am able to consume the service but when I do it on my Android device from a Login page it shows the following "Message":

```
"Authorization has been denied for this request."
```

My Web Api is hosted in a SQL Database in AZURE.
I am making use of the following method to validate the token:

```
public async Task<TokenResponse> GetToken(string urlBase, string username, string password)
        {
            try
            {
                var client = new HttpClient();
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri(urlBase);
                var response = await client.PostAsync("Token",
                    new StringContent(string.Format(
                    "grant_type=password&username={0}&password={1}",
                    username, password),
                    Encoding.UTF8, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"));
                var resultJSON = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TokenResponse>(
                    resultJSON);
                return result;
            }
            catch
            {
                return null;
            }
```

Does anyone has an idea of what is happening?

Comment: You question is so unreadable. please format the code parts in nice format so one can read.

Comment: Please add the `DefaultRequestHeaders` for your `HttpClient`: `client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Token", new StringContent(string.Format("grant_type=password&username={0}&password{1}",username, password));` and then try to post your data to the API

Comment: Remove the Authorize attribute or register a user ,then login to user's token , please refer https://stackoverflow.com/a/38963935/8187800